# ST3 Plugin append selection to end of new file

Tags: plugins, sublimetext3

I've been experimenting with some Sublime Text 3 plugins and I am in the process of making one which adds the view selection to the end of a new file.

```
    import sublime
    import sublime_plugin


    class AddToCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit):
            # text = sublime.Region(0, view.size())
            window = self.view.window()
            view = self.view
            s = ''
            for region in view.sel():
                if not region.empty():
                    s += '\n' + view.substr(region)
            print(s)
            for v in window.views():
                print(v.name())
                if v.name() == 'untitled':
                    f = v
                    break
            else:  # if no break occurs --> no current view called [untitled]
                f = window.new_file()
            # print(self)
            # print(edit)
            # print(f)
            window.focus_view(f)
            f.run_command('insert_in_new_file', view.sel())


    class InsertInNewFileCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit, selection):
            self.count = 0  # not using enumerate as it goes through 2 loops
            for line in selection:
                for char in line:
                    self.insert(edit, self.count, char)
                    self.count += 1
                self.insert(edit, self.count, '\n')
                self.count += 1
```

I've got this far and it checks (in a basic way) for an already open file, so now I'm trying to make it append to the end of this 'untitled' file. However, when I run this code, I get an error:

```
    f.run_command('insert_in_new_file', view.sel())
        File "C:\Users\ ... \Sublime Text 3\sublime.py", line 838, in run_command
            sublime_api.view_run_command(self.view_id, cmd, args)
    TypeError: Value required
```

It seems there is something wrong with my InsertInNewFile class or the calling of it's .run command, but the lack of ST3 plugin documentation means I cannot find any similar problem or solution

Answer (score 1):

The `run_command` expects a command name as first and a json dictionary (as a mapping from keywords to values) as second argument.

Let's start with this

```py
f.run_command('insert_in_new_file', view.sel())
```

You second argument is `sublime.Selection` object, which is neither json  compatible nor a dict. So we create a dict:

```py
f.run_command('insert_in_new_file', { "selection": view.sel() })
```

Now it is a dict (and the key is the same as in the formal parameters of the run method), but it not json compatible, so it will raise an error. We can fix this by converting the selection into a list of tuples:

```py
f.run_command('insert_in_new_file', { "selection": list((s.a, s.b) for s in view.sel()) })
```

Now the call will be successful, but you also need to handle the parameters correctly.
Based on the code there, you expect a list of strings and not a list of file positions. So we can change the argument again to pass the content of the selections instead of the selection itself and skip empty selections:

```py
f.run_command('insert_in_new_file', { "selection": list(view.substr(s) for s in view.sel() if len(s)) })
```

Afterwards replace `self.insert(edit, self.count, char)` by `self.view.insert(edit, self.count, char)` and it should work.